# NotifyBuilder behaves inconsistently on repetitive runs

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I want to make end-to-end testing of my application and I need to make sure Camel routes work fine. I use NotifyBuilder to make sure message is completed, and since consuming message takes some time I want to let it 30 seconds to be processed (but if message completed sooner it should not wait) and then proceed with verification. This works fine, but... but unfortunately from time to time NotifyBuilder doesn't react on message completion, but my log messages are stating that all required steps are done. This happens not always, but regularly, 2 times from ten runs in average. What is interesting, I use such approach in several tests, and they fail with this issue randomly, usually one at a time (all the others pass).

After debugging Camel code a bit, I noticed that methods `org.apache.camel.builder.NotifyBuilder.EventPredicateSupport#onExchangeCompleted` and `org.apache.camel.builder.NotifyBuilder.EventPredicateSupport#onExchange` are not invoked for some reasons, even when corresponding event has been fired.

Also I noticed that when running tests in isolation (one at a time), everything works as expected. Also when I send one and the same message twice NotifyBuilder calls `org.apache.camel.builder.NotifyBuilder.EventPredicateSupport#onExchangeCompleted` only for the second message.

I use camel 2.18.3 and JDK 8u60. OS Linux Mint 17 and CentOS (on Windows seems like everything works fine). Tests are executed in a single thread by gradle task in command line.

Does anyone have an idea what can be the reason for such a behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my test class code and camel configuration:

```
public class EndToEndTest {

    @Resource(name = "camelContext")
    private CamelContext camelContext;
    @Produce(uri = "activemq:fromQueueName")
    private ProducerTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void testWithNotifyBuilder() {
        NotifyBuilder notify = new NotifyBuilder(camelContext)
            .whenCompleted(1)
            .from("activemq:fromQueueName")
            .create();
        template.sendBody("{\"json\":\"example\"}");
        assertTrue(notify.matches(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        // other verifications
    }}

<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<!-- other endpoints and beans -->
<endpoint id="fromEndpoint" uri="activemq:fromQueueName"/>
<route>
    <from ref="fromEndpoint"/>
    <unmarshal>
        <custom ref="customMessageUnmarshaller"/>
    </unmarshal>
    <bean ref="customMessageConsumer"/>

    <onException redeliveryPolicyRef="defaultRedeliveryPolicy">
        <exception>java.net.SocketException</exception>
        <exception>javax.jms.JMSException</exception>
        <handled>
            <constant>true</constant>
        </handled>
    </onException>
</route>
<!-- other routes -->
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the order of your predicates to `.from("activemq:fromQueueName").whenCompleted(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem, the issue was with the camel context not properly being reset after each test. The issue could be fixed using Springboot [`@DirtiesContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) annotation.

The issue I had was similar, inconsistent tests passing, and the build failing in Jenkins due to random tests failing (even though they passed locally). The issue was the Camel context being used in each Unit Test wasn't always being reset after each test. Causing camel to enter a polling loop and failing at the `NotifyBuilder.matchsMockWaitTime()` timeout.

by placing

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

at the top of your test class, the context used is reset after each test is run. This ensures your camel context isn't attempting to use old routes when running multiple tests, causing a polling loop.

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class DeadChannelTest {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext context;

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void testMoveFile() throws Exception {
        // use NotifyBuilder to wait for the file to be routed
        NotifyBuilder notify = new NotifyBuilder(context).whenDone(1).create();

        // create a new file in the inbox folder with the name hello.txt and containing Hello World as body
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("file://camel/route",
                FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(TestPath), "UTF-8"),
                Exchange.FILE_NAME,
                "testError.log");

        // notifier will wait for the file to be processed
        // and if that never happen it will time out after 10 seconds (default mock timeout)
        assertTrue(notify.matchesMockWaitTime());

        // test the file was moved
        File target = new File(ErrorFolder + "/testError.log");
        assertTrue("File should have been moved", target.exists());
    }
```

Comment: Can you please enhance your answer a bit, for example how you've used it and where you've added this annotation to? This would make it clearer for future readers how to fix a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is now a very nice answer :).